# "She scored high marks in all her subjects"

Tags: prepositions

I wonder why we should use the preposition *in* instead of *at* here

> She scored high marks *in* all her subjects.

Answer (score 1):

When she is good **at** math she scores high marks **in** math.

**at** here introduces a subject as something to which we apply our efforts and where we use our skills.  It expresses the relationship of the student or devotee to the subject.

**in** in this context introduces a subject as a discipline, a "subject area" in its own right.